# How to set Kiosk mode on Windows Server 2012/2016/2019 correctly?

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop, rdp

I wish to set Kiosk mode on Windows Server 2012, and I follow this tutorial
https://purerds.org/remote-desktop-scripts/remote-desktop-kiosk-mode-windows-server-2016

I try to follow but I don't understand how exact to replace these strings

```
[string]$RDSHostName, [string]$Domainname, [string]$Username, [string]$Password, [string]$PathToStartupProgram, [string]$PathToWorkingDirectory
```

For example, when I launch a RDP session I want to launch and view only a program called *CDisplayEx* located into `C:\Program Files\CDisplayEx` and program is called **CDisplayEx.exe**

Username is `Administrator` and password is, for example, `JgjhOjhg78g`.

How should I replace ?

Before to make this I restore `tsconfig` on Windows Server 2012 and I place this data

```
domain: WORKGROUP
username: Administrator
password: JgjhOjhg78g
repeat password: JgjhOjhg78g
```

Answer (score 0):

That tutorial is telling you to execute the script `CacheLogonAndSetProgram.ps1` and pass those variables as arguments.

```
powershell.exe CacheLogonAndSetProgram.ps1 -RDSHostName "myrdshostname" -Domainname "mydomain.com" ...
```

(incomplete example above (replace `...` with your other params) - basically you need to pass each variable mentioned as shown. Above example assumes your using CMD and are in the directory where `CacheLogonAndSetProgram.ps1` lives)